# Making a method that's usable by a rectangle object

Tags: java

I was wondering what's wrong with this code trying to have a method that a rectangle can call and have the rectangle moved by two ints it passes in, here's what I have so far,

```
import java.awt.*;

public class rectangles
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Rectangle h = new Rectangle();
        h.moveRectangle(5, 5);
    }
    public static Rectangle moveRectangle(Rectangle h, int x, int y)
    {
        h.move(x, y);
        return h;
    }
}
```

I have the error on `h.moveRectangle(5, 5);`  saying "The method moveRectangle(int, int) is undefined for the type Rectangle.". Sorry for the really beginner question.

Comment: Change the call to `moveRectangle(h, 5, 5);`

Comment: This looks like you are coming from a language which supports "mixins"; Java doesn't, so you can't arbitrarily augment a class without modifying or subclassing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use your own method you should call method of your class `rectangles` but not method of the class `java.awt.Rectangle`. It should be

```
rectangles.moveRectangle(h, 5, 5);
```